# Why do we discard 2 fibonacci numbers in fibnacci search, if value at current index is less than what we're trying to find?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search, fibonacci

I have code that does Fibonacci search and I was wondering why we discard 2 Fibonacci numbers if our key is greater than the value at current index in the array?

```java
public class FibSearch{
    static int fibSearch(int[] a, int x){
        int f1 = 1, f2 = 0, mid = 2;
        while(f1 < a.length){
            f1 = f1 + f2;
            f2 = f1 - f2;
            mid++;
        }

        int first = 0;
        mid--;
        f2 = f1 - f2;
        f1 = f1 - f2;

        while(mid > 0){
            int index = first + f1;
            if(index >= a.length || a[index] > x){
                mid--;
                f2 = f1 - f2;
                f1 = f1 - f2;
            }
            else if(a[index] == x){
                return index;
            }
            else{
                first = index;
                mid = mid - 2;
                f1 = f1 - f2;
                f2 = f2 - f1;
                //why not write
                //mid = mid - 1;
                //f2 = f1 - f2;
                //f1 = f1 - f2;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The last else statement if what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if we have a Fibonacci sequence : 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,... F(k - 1) + F(k - 3) is what falls in the middle between F(k - 1) and F(k), and that's what we want because it's divide and conquer.